# How to tell MonetDB that data are sorted in the table?

Tags: database, indexing, monetdb

Given a table `data` (as described below) and given the insurance that that values imported into this table are sorted.

```
CREATE TABLE data (INT value) 
CREATE INDEX index_value ON data (value)
```

Since MonetDB can neglect the `CREATE INDEX` statement (see details [here](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/Indices)). How do I tell MonetDB that data are sorted in order to let him improves lookup operations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.monetdb.org/pipermail/users-list/2015-March/007932.html (edited) :

> MonetDB will detect it automagically. Just make sure the data is indeed ordered upon load. You can check it using the call

```
select "column","sorted" from storage() where "table"='yourtable';
```

> which contains a column indicating whether MonetDB detected the sorted order.

Please don't double-post both here and on the MonetDB mailing list.